# Unable to cast String to Json Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Data in Select2 load correctly with Static Data

```
 $('#placeSelect').select2({
            width: '100%',
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: true,
            maximumSelectionSize: 2,
            placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
            data:  
                [{ id: "1", text: "Afghanistan" }, { id: "2", text: "Africa CAMEU region, nes" }]

        });
```

**When I try to make it dynamic using string .**

```
var _stringJson= '[{id:"1","text":"Afghanistan"},{id:"2","text":"Africa CAMEU region, nes"}]'

 json = JSON.parse(_stringJson);
 $('#placeSelect').select2({
            width: '100%',
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: true,
            maximumSelectionSize: 2,
            placeholder: "Click here and start typing to search.",
            data:json 

        });
```

It's work now. 
**updated**

```
 var _stringJson= '[{id:"1",text:"Afghanistan"},{id:"2",text:"Africa CAMEU region, nes"}]'
```

**With**

```
var _stringJson= '[{id:"1","text":"Afghanistan"},{id:"2","text":"Africa CAMEU region, nes"}]'
```

Comment: `var _stringJson= "[{id:"1",text:"Afghanistan"}` Can you find the Syntax Error? Use single quotes for outside.

Comment: You'll need to parse the string into JSON (hint words: *parse*, *json*, *encode*, *decode*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. Incorrect quotations `"`s.
2. Stringification of a String!

You need:

```
// Quotes
var _stringJson= '[{"id":"1","text":"Afghanistan"},{"id":"2","text":"Africa CAMEU region, nes"}]';
// Use Parse
json = JSON.parse(_stringJson);
```

Comment: I have made the suggested changes, still it's not working.

Comment: Error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2

Comment: @RohitKumar Updated answer.

Comment: Now Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 11

Comment: @RohitKumar Updated again. `:(`

Comment: Please update the answer with Replace text with "text"